# Copying text from file into another and edit resulting file

Tags: python, text

I'm trying to write a function that will generate a series of files using text from another file. The issue I'm having is that I want to add text to the end of the line that was written  from file. In addition to this, I want the added text to be dependent on what line I'm in.

The source file looks something like this:

```
C1      1.00964527   -0.31216598   -0.03471416
C2      2.46197796   -0.03537534   -0.02239528
C3      3.13892016   -1.29949550   -0.01824029
N1      0.78031101   -1.74687208   -0.03258816
N2      2.41533961   -3.71674253   -0.03080008
H1      6.38746003   -0.16735186    0.01037509
H2      5.06643233   -2.35376889   -0.00392019
H3      2.64230377    2.15284044   -0.01822299
Cu1    -0.97960685   -2.67533229   -0.06199922
```

The goal is to generate an output file that has two columns additional columns at the end where the values of the new columns would be determined via inputs to the function.

```
C1      1.00964527   -0.31216598   -0.03471416  6 32
C2      2.46197796   -0.03537534   -0.02239528  4 32
C3      3.13892016   -1.29949550   -0.01824029  4 32
N1      0.78031101   -1.74687208   -0.03258816  7 32
N2      2.41533961   -3.71674253   -0.03080008  7 32
H1      6.38746003   -0.16735186    0.01037509  1 32
H2      5.06643233   -2.35376889   -0.00392019  1 32
H3      2.64230377    2.15284044   -0.01822299  1 32
Cu1    -0.97960685   -2.67533229   -0.06199922 29 32
```

The following portion of the code copies the contents of the source file and pastes them onto the output file.

```py
def makeGNDrun(fname, aname, nAtoms):
    i = 1
    for i in range(1, nAtoms + 1):

        f = open(str(aname) + str(i) + "_gnd.run", "w+")

        with open(fname + ".xyz") as f:
            with open(aname + str(i) + "_gnd.run", "a+") as f1:
                for line in f:
                    f1.write(line)
```

I'm unsure as to how to add the last two columns however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then you can do something like that:

```py
def makeGNDrun(fname, aname, nAtoms):
    for i in range(1, nAtoms + 1):

        # open two files together... first in read-mode and the other in append-mode
        with open(str(aname) + str(i) + "_gnd.run", "r") as f, \
             open(aname + str(i) + "_gnd.run", "a") as f1:

             # iterate over lines of f which is in read-mode
             for line in f.readlines():
                 # line is read from f, so you can modify it before writting it to f1
                 # here I will append " i  32" to it
                 line = line.strip() + '\t' + str(i) + '\t' + str(32) + '\n'
                 f1.write(line)
```

Hopefully, this is what you meant!!

Comment: That's pretty close! Unfortunately, the columns are not being added to the correct line for some reason. With the exception of the very last line, the added columns are added to the next line for some reason.

Comment: ooh, so sorry. I forgot to use `strip()` with line. I've edited my answer. Could you try one more time

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas you open the text file, and apply your **own custom function** to the column you need and store the result in another column. Then save the result.

```
import pandas as pd

def function1(colA, colB, colC):
    return colA + colB - colC

def function2(colA, colB, colC):
    return colA * colB / colC

t = pd.read_csv(r"...\text.txt", sep='\s+', names=['idx', 'colA', 'colB', 'colC'], index_col='idx')

t["Result_1"] = t.apply(lambda x: function1(x['colA'], x['colB'], x["colC"]), axis=1)
t["Result_2"] = t.apply(lambda x: function2(x['colA'], x['colB'], x["colC"]), axis=1)

t.to_csv(r"...\Result.txt", sep='\t')
```

This :

```
C1      1.00964527   -0.31216598   -0.03471416
C2      2.46197796   -0.03537534   -0.02239528
C3      3.13892016   -1.29949550   -0.01824029
N1      0.78031101   -1.74687208   -0.03258816
N2      2.41533961   -3.71674253   -0.03080008
H1      6.38746003   -0.16735186    0.01037509
H2      5.06643233   -2.35376889   -0.00392019
H3      2.64230377    2.15284044   -0.01822299
Cu1    -0.97960685   -2.67533229   -0.06199922
```

Become this:

```
idx colA        colB        colC        Result_1    Result_2
C1  1.00964527  -0.31216598 -0.03471416 0.73219345  9.07920298696309
C2  2.46197796  -0.03537534 -0.02239528 2.4489979   3.8889135303289977
C3  3.13892016  -1.2994955  -0.01824029 1.8576649500000002  223.62652253770528
N1  0.78031101  -1.74687208 -0.03258816 -0.9339729099999999 41.82818290709266
N2  2.41533961  -3.71674253 -0.03080008 -1.2706028399999998 291.4666277776101
H1  6.38746003  -0.16735186 0.01037509  6.2097330799999995  -103.03075122202851
H2  5.06643233  -2.35376889 -0.00392019 2.7165836299999997  3041.9981688755424
H3  2.64230377  2.15284044  -0.01822299 4.8133672   -312.15834562936476
Cu1 -0.97960685 -2.67533229 -0.06199922 -3.59293992 -42.2710775604949
```